# Fabric - Crashlytics Console Does Not Show Logs

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I am experiencing an issue with Fabric and Crashlytics that I can't seem to figure out and I was hoping someone could help me. My Android app doesn't seem to send logs and properties on a fatal crash when it's deployed in Google Play.

This is strange so I decided to because I have tried creating a release build using Android Studio directly onto my phone and purposefully throw a fatal exception. If I do that, I get logs and properties displaying in the Fabric console when looking at the crash.

I assumed it was related to either the Crashlytics versions or perhaps the target SDK version of the app itself. The fact that it works when I directly place the release app on my phone is confusing me. Is there something I am missing? Seeing the logs and properties are extremely helpful to debug crashes so not having this behaviour in production is worrisome.

**app/build.gradle:**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 27

...

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

**project/build.gradle:**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

**Application class onCreate():**

```
    Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()
            .disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build();

    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

Comment: I think you added wrong package name on crashlytics.

Comment: What do you mean? In my gradle file?

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. I don't see anything wrong with your Gradle files or main activity, so it may be an issue with your application's state on our backend. Please email support(at)fabric(dot)io with your package and organization name and we can help you there.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Will do.

Comment: FYI This is still happening.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I get logs for logged exceptions most (90%+) of the time but sometimes they are missing

Comment: Sorry Ewan, no I did not.

Comment: @JPM, maybe consider transision to Firebase Crashlytics. Functionality is almost the same, and either way, fabric Crashlytics will be shut down in near future.